# Sending S/MIME Signed Mails with Django

Tags: python, django, sendgrid, sign, smime

Is there a way to use the wrappers provided by Django to send signed or even encrypted emails?
We use S/MIME in our company and it's required that all mails are signed.
I currently send emails via SendGrid:

```python
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "<email_password>"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Answer (score 0):

It's funny I just got the same assignment this week and came here hoping you or another member found a solution :)

I pulled of this one using the package `M2Crypto`, basically it's just adapted from [this example](https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/-/blob/master/doc/howto.smime.rst) provided in the docs/ folder of the package.

Please note that in my case I changed Cipher to aes_256_cbc and that sent email need to be both signed and encrypted or I'm not able to decrypt to theses mails in Outlook client because of some header issue.

```
from M2Crypto import BIO, SMIME, X509
import smtplib
from django.conf import settings

def sendsmime(from_addr, to_addrs, subject, msg, from_key, from_cert=None, to_certs=None):
    msg_bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer(msg)
    sign = from_key
    encrypt = to_certs

    s = SMIME.SMIME()
    if sign:
        s.load_key(from_key, from_cert)
        if encrypt:
            p7 = s.sign(msg_bio, flags=SMIME.PKCS7_TEXT)
        else:
            p7 = s.sign(msg_bio, flags=SMIME.PKCS7_TEXT | SMIME.PKCS7_DETACHED)
        msg_bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer(msg)  # Recreate coz sign() has consumed it.

    if encrypt:
        sk = X509.X509_Stack()
        for x in to_certs:
            sk.push(X509.load_cert(x))
        s.set_x509_stack(sk)
        s.set_cipher(SMIME.Cipher('aes_256_cbc'))
        tmp_bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer()
        if sign:
            s.write(tmp_bio, p7)
        else:
            tmp_bio.write(msg)
        p7 = s.encrypt(tmp_bio)

    out = BIO.MemoryBuffer()
    out.write('From: %s\r\n' % from_addr)
    out.write('To: %s\r\n' % ", ".join(to_addrs))
    out.write('Subject: %s\r\n' % subject)
    if encrypt:
        s.write(out, p7)
    else:
        if sign:
            s.write(out, p7, msg_bio, SMIME.PKCS7_TEXT)
        else:
            out.write('\r\n')
            out.write(msg)
    out.close()

    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(settings.EMAIL_HOST, settings.EMAIL_PORT)
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, out.read())
    smtp.quit()
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate why the email needs to be both signed and encrypted? When I encrypt and sign everything seems to work but when I want to sign only, Outlook claims that the message has been altered and I cannot figure aut why that is the case. Is this the same behaviour you encountered?